# Error: "Missing options. Please supply all options for android signing" while building Android build

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, gradle

How can i fix this problem?
Error: "Missing options. Please supply all options for android signing. [Keystore Path, Keystore Password, Keystore Key Alias, Keystore Key Password,"
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4dCE.png)

I tried this: https://coderwall.com/p/r09hoq/android-generate-release-debug-keystores
But don't sure this is what i need

Comment: I resolved this err.

Comment: How did you resolved this error, can you please describe it?